# Force acting on an object in a non inertial frame

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces

In my textbook of mechanics I had a doubt related to the following text:-

1. In all system of reference which are in uniform rectilinear motion relative to each other the acceleration of the moving body is the same.
2. Experiments show that the forces acting on the bodies and the mass of the bodies are independent of the choice of any of these systems of reference relative to which the motions of the bodies are considered.
3. The forces depend on the distance between the bodies, on their relative velocities, and on time, all these quantities not varying when we pass from one system of reference to another system of reference which is in a uniform rectilinear motion w.r.t the former.

I cant seem to get my head around the $3rd$ point, how can a force be dependent on the distance between the bodies, relative velocities of the bodies, and on time. I cant seem to find any example in the real world to supplement this point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not necessarily the same force acting at the same time.
You have been given three examples of forces which do not shange as you pass from one system of reference to another.

Force $F$ depends on distance $r \Rightarrow F(r) = \dfrac{Gm_1m_2}{r^2}$ which is Newton's law of gravitation.

Force $F$ depends on the relative velocity $v$ between a mass moving through a fluid $\Rightarrow F(v) = kv^2$ or $F(v)=kv$ which is due to the viscosity of the fluid.

Force $F$ depends on time $\Rightarrow F(t) = at^2 +bt$ etc or any other time dependent relationship for the force.